# How to read CPU name in T32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

Using t32 "sys.cpu" command we can set CPU but if we want to write CMM script which that do orocessing depending on CPU version then how we can read sys.cpu value to get CPU name in cmm

Answer (score 3):

Please use function CPU().

Example:
SYStem.CPU CortexA15

PRINT CPU()

will print the result
"CortexA15"
into the AREA window.

Comment: Thanks Phillip its working and can see CPU name in area window but not able to capture in variable may be area contents need to pick

Comment: CPU() is a function returning a string. So you can assign the return value to a macro: "&myname=CPU()"